# Qt app text stream on console

Tags: c++, qt, console

I have seen many modes to show console messages on Qt. But, what differences are between them:

- Using iostream and std::cin
- use Qdebug
- Use QTextStream

In what cases is better to use each one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<iostream>` header and `std::cout`(*) variable are part of the standard C++ library rather than a Qt specific feature. If you use other non-Qt-based external libraries in your project, it's more likely that classes defined in those libraries provide stream operator overloads and other features that are compatible with these C++ streams. For instance, if you build a graph object using the Boost Graph Library, you could easily print a Graphviz representation of it to a `std::cout` stream.

On the other hand, `QTextStream` handles Qt objects, specially `QString`, which saves you from having to convert between `std::string` our `char*` and `QString` and vice-versa. If your project  is Qt-centric or uses only Qt-based external libraries, it's likely that `QTextStream` will save you some work.

Notice also that `QTextStream` handles by default some locale and character encoding on different platforms by using `QTextCodec::codecForLocale()`. `std::cout`, on the contrary, defaults to using the `"C"` locale and makes no encoding handling between `std::string`/`char*` and the system encoding. Therefore, using `QTextStream`might help if you're developing a cross-platform system that needs encoding and locale awareness, as you would need to manually set-up the `std::cout` do do these conversions through calls to the `imbue()` method, for instance.

(*) - Notice that `std::cin` is for reading from the console. `std::cout` is for standard output. The C++ standard library also provides `std::cerr` for error output and `std::clog` for log output.

Comment: You forgot the QDebug part. QDebug uses QTextStream internally. It is a convenience class to open a stream on a IO device. The most simple way to use it is to call `qDebug() << somestring`. You can define `operator()<<` on QDebug for your custom types.